# Npm homepage not working

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have a question, I'm the creator of https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-ts and I don't know how to put the link to the GitHub repo in the right column

I already try the homepage:

"homepage":"https://github.com/nicolasgere/graphql-ts"

someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it for me:

```
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/lucastheisen/saxtract.git"
  },
```